# How do I add an object to the database using Linq to SQL?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I'm trying to learn LINQ to SQL and I'm able to query the database and get back an IQueryable and manipulate the objects I retrieve from that. But I've no idea how to add a new object back into the database or into the original IQueryable.

```
private DataContext db;
private IQueryable<ActionType> action;

public void BuildQuery(string connection) {
    db = new DataContext(connection);
    action = db.GetTable<ActionType>().Select(a=>a);

    ActionType at = new ActionType();
    at.Name = "New Action Type";

    // What now? action.add(at) || db.GetTable<ActionType>.add(at); ??
}
```

It's a suprisingly hard thing to search for if you don't know the right terms. And I can't find any examples that do exactly what I want them to do.

So, how do I go about adding new objects to a query/database?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To insert your newly created instance of "ActionType", you need add your object to the data context (and "add" was renamed to "InsertOnSubmit" during Linq-to-SQL beta) and then call SubmitChanges on the data context:

```
public void BuildQuery(string connection) {
    db = new DataContext(connection);
    action = db.GetTable<ActionType>().Select(a=>a);

    ActionType at = new ActionType();
    at.Name = "New Action Type";

    // What now? action.add(at) || db.GetTable<ActionType>.add(at); ??
    db.ActionTypes.InsertOnSubmit(at);
    db.SubmitChanges();
}
```

See [this blog post here](http://autocreate.wordpress.com/2008/04/28/linq-to-sql-pay-attention-to-the-two-ways-of-adding-objects/) why you should be using `InsertOnSubmit` over `Attach`.

Marc

Comment: Shouldn't it be something like this : db.ActionTypes.InsertOnSubmit(at);

Answer (score 2):

```
private DataContext db;
private IQueryable<ActionType> action;

public void BuildQuery(string connection) {
   db = new DataContext(connection);
   action = db.GetTable<ActionType>().Select(a=>a);

   ActionType at = new ActionType();
   at.Name = "New Action Type";

   //There must be a table like ActionType and it seems ActionTypes when calling it ith   // db
   db.ActionTypes.InsertOnSubmit(at);
   db.SubmitChanges();
}
```

You can see a nice example here : [Click Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763516.aspx)

Comment: No problem it happens sometimes :)

Answer (score 0):

Now all you need to do is submit your changes back to the database:

```
db.Attach(at);
db.SubmitChanges();
```

Comment: I believe you should be using `InsertOnSubmit` instead of Attach

Answer (score 0):

I'd wrap the DataContext within a using statement - it ensures it is disposed of, when the operation is complete.

Like this:

```
public void BuildQuery(string connection) 
{
    using (var db = new DataContext(connection))
    {
        action = db.GetTable<ActionType>().Select(a=>a);

        ActionType at = new ActionType();
        at.Name = "New Action Type";

        // What now? action.add(at) || db.GetTable<ActionType>.add(at); ??
        db.ActionTypes.InsertOnSubmit(at);
        db.SubmitChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm going to be using the datacontext in future operations. It's instantiated in the contructor. For the purpose of this question, I rearranged things so it was all visible. But thanks for the heads up in the future.